# Parallel Computation Overhead

Tags: java, multithreading, compiler-construction, parallel-processing

I am using the following code as part of a `CompilerPhase` class. The method gets called (and benchmarked) by the main method of the compiler.

ParallelCompilerPhase:

```
private Consumer<ICompilationUnit> apply;
// ...

@Override
public void apply(Collection<ICompilationUnit> units)
{
    this.count = units.size();
    for (ICompilationUnit unit : units)
    {
        new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                ParallelCompilerPhase.this.apply.accept(unit);
                ParallelCompilerPhase.this.count--;
            }
        }.start();
    }

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (this.count > 0)
    {
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis() - now;
        if (l >= 1000L)
        {
            DyvilCompiler.logger.warning(this.name + " is taking too long! " + l + " ms");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CompilerPhase:

```
private Consumer<Collection<ICompilationUnit>> apply;
//...

@Override
public void apply(Collection<ICompilationUnit> units)
{
    this.apply.accept(units);
}
```

With the old implementation (`CompilerPhase`), the entire process (of 11 different phases) took 40-60 ms to compile 1 Compilation Unit. However, the new implementation (`ParallelCompilerPhase`) adds 2000 ms of overhead to this. The phases `TOKENIZE`, `PARSE`, `RESOLVE_TYPES`, `RESOLVE`, `CHECK`, `PRINT` and `COMPILE` use `ParallelCompilerPhase`.

Here is the output of the Compiler:

```
[2015-03-04 23:16:49] [INFO]: Loaded 2 Libraries (235.7 ms, 117.9 ms/L, 8.48 L/s)
[2015-03-04 23:16:49] [INFO]: Compiling 'src/test' to 'dbin'
[2015-03-04 23:16:49] [INFO]: Applying 8 States: [TOKENIZE, PARSE, RESOLVE_TYPES, RESOLVE, CHECK, PRINT, COMPILE, TEST]
[2015-03-04 23:16:49] [INFO]: Compiling 2 Packages, 2 Files (1 Compilation Unit)

[2015-03-04 23:16:49] [INFO]: Applying State TOKENIZE
[2015-03-04 23:16:49] [INFO]: Finished State TOKENIZE (2.4 ms, 2.4 ms/CU, 423.19 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:16:49] [INFO]: Applying State PARSE
[2015-03-04 23:16:50] [WARNING]: PARSE is taking too long! 1000 ms
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Finished State PARSE (2005.1 ms, 2005.1 ms/CU, 0.50 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Applying State RESOLVE_TYPES
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Finished State RESOLVE_TYPES (17.1 ms, 17.1 ms/CU, 58.35 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Applying State RESOLVE
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Finished State RESOLVE (24.0 ms, 24.0 ms/CU, 41.70 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Applying State CHECK
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Finished State CHECK (0.5 ms, 0.5 ms/CU, 1838.24 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Applying State PRINT
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: src/test/dyvil/test/Main.dyvil:
// ...
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Finished State PRINT (42.3 ms, 42.3 ms/CU, 23.61 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Applying State COMPILE
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Finished State COMPILE (5.2 ms, 5.2 ms/CU, 192.64 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Applying State TEST
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Finished State TEST (46.0 ms, 46.0 ms/CU, 21.72 CU/s)

[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Compilation finished (2148.6 ms, 2148.6 ms/CU, 0.47 CU/s)
// ...
[2015-03-04 23:16:51] [INFO]: Test completed without Errors (1 ms)
```

However, if I change the implementation of `ParallelCompilerPhase` to this:

```
@Override
public void apply(Collection<ICompilationUnit> units)
{
    for (ICompilationUnit unit : units)
    {
        this.apply.accept(unit);
    }
}
```

The output of the Compiler looks like this:

```
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Dyvil Compiler 1.0.0 for Dyvil 1.0.0

[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Loaded 2 Libraries (245.6 ms, 122.8 ms/L, 8.14 L/s)
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Compiling 'src/test' to 'dbin'
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying 8 States: [TOKENIZE, PARSE, RESOLVE_TYPES, RESOLVE, CHECK, PRINT, COMPILE, TEST]
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Compiling 2 Packages, 2 Files (1 Compilation Unit)

[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying State TOKENIZE
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Finished State TOKENIZE (0.6 ms, 0.6 ms/CU, 1721.17 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying State PARSE
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Finished State PARSE (20.6 ms, 20.6 ms/CU, 48.59 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying State RESOLVE_TYPES
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Finished State RESOLVE_TYPES (8.5 ms, 8.5 ms/CU, 117.34 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying State RESOLVE
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Finished State RESOLVE (15.9 ms, 15.9 ms/CU, 63.07 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying State CHECK
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Finished State CHECK (0.2 ms, 0.2 ms/CU, 4587.16 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying State PRINT
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: src/test/dyvil/test/Main.dyvil:
// ...
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Finished State PRINT (2.1 ms, 2.1 ms/CU, 479.39 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying State COMPILE
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Finished State COMPILE (4.0 ms, 4.0 ms/CU, 251.76 CU/s)
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Applying State TEST
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Finished State TEST (0.6 ms, 0.6 ms/CU, 1686.34 CU/s)

[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Compilation finished (57.5 ms, 57.5 ms/CU, 17.40 CU/s)
// ...
[2015-03-04 23:21:36] [INFO]: Test completed without Errors (2 ms)
```

What is causing this 2000 ms overhead?

---

As a possible fix, would replacing the implementation of `ParallelCompilerPhase` with

```
units.parallelStream().forEach(this.apply);
```

do what I initially wanted to do with my Thread approach?

Comment: The definition of insanity for parallel programmers is to do the same thing over and over and expect the same result :P

Comment: Note that I have *at least* 2000 ms overhead *every time* (when running in Eclipse), while the 40-60 ms measurement was accurate for the last [insert ridiculous number] tests before using `ParallelCompilerPhase`...

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what apply is doing... But if it is a short task and you have thousands of them, the overhead of starting a new thread may be higher than the benefit of parallelism...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ParallelCompilerPhase, the following happens

- the new threads are created
- the main thread stays busy checking `this.count` and the time, so the new threads don't run
- after 1000ms, the message is printed and the main thread sleeps for 1000ms
- the other threads execute and finish
- the main thread awakes and 2005.1ms have passed.

The problem is the busy loop.
Try:

```
@Override
public void apply(Collection<ICompilationUnit> units)
{
    this.count = units.size();
    for (ICompilationUnit unit : units)
    {
        new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                ParallelCompilerPhase.this.apply.accept(unit);
                ParallelCompilerPhase.this.count--;
            }
        }.start();
    }

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (this.count > 0)
    {
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis() - now;
        if (l >= 1000L)
        {
            DyvilCompiler.logger.warning(this.name + " is taking too long! " + l + " ms");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10L);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, the best way to wait for the threads would be to use `Thread.join()`, as suggested by @rici, because this would be the 'official way' to do that, and would not cause any waste of processor time. With the solution above, the main thread waits for an additional time of up to 10ms after the workers have finished, with `join()` the main thread would awake immediately when the workers have finished.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new thread for each unit of work. This is a *terrible* idea. For any computationally-bound task (one that doesn't spend the majority of its time blocking waiting for IO), there is never any reason to have more threads than you have CPU cores. All exceeding this threshold will do is waste time context switching between the threads (and waste a lot of time spinning up and tearing down threads, which isn't cheap). Your processor can't actually do more things simultaneously than it has processor resources, no matter how many threads are in flight.

Instead, you should look into using an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) to manage a [thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) for you and simply have the worker threads pop off units of work from a queue and execute them.